# Chess960 castling controversy in the 2019 WFRCC: Where can I see the original Nepo vs Wesley So game?

Tags: history, chess-variants, world-championship, castling, chess960

Apparently in the 5th game Ian Nepomniachtchi [originally](https://chess24.com/en/read/news/carlsen-and-so-to-play-fischer-random-final) had to play 13. Rf1 instead of 13. 0-0 but then they allowed Nepo to replay the whole game.

The ff is the replay game:

https://lichess.org/broadcast/fischer-random-championship-semifinals-game-5/fischer-random-championship-semifinals-game-5/KCQKpdn7/xnov008A#16

Where can I see the original game please?

Comment: What does "_ff_" mean?

Comment: ff means following